# Invalid keyframe value for property transform: transform: translateX(0px) translateZ(0px) in angular animation

Tags: angular, transform, angular-animations

I have this simple animation:

```
trigger('slide', [
    state(
        'true',
        style({
            transform: 'transform: translateX(0px) translateZ(0px)',
            opacity: 1,
        }),
    ),
    state('false', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%) translateZ(0px)', opacity: 0 })),
    transition('* => *', animate(200)),
]),
```

which I use on my menu component like this:

```
 [@slide]="isExpanded"
```

It works, but chrome has this warning:

> Invalid keyframe value for property transform: transform: translateX(0px) translateZ(0px)

Does anyone know why?

Comment: transform: 'transform: translateX(0px) translateZ(0px)', That second transform doesn’t belong there

Comment: why not use `translate3D(100%,0,0)`? I don't like too much use together translateX and translateZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was me being silly, the first transform is wrong:

```
transform: 'transform: translateX(0px) translateZ(0px)',
```

It has an extra **transform** which isn't needed.
Changing it to this:

```
animations: [
    trigger('slide', [
        state(
            'true',
            style({
                transform: 'translateX(0px) translateZ(0px)',
                opacity: 1,
            }),
        ),
        state('false', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%) translateZ(0px)', opacity: 0 })),
        transition('* => *', animate(200)),
    ]),
],
```

Fixed the issue